# Does JQueries Live Work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making use of the [JQuery fancy box](http://fancybox.net/) - in this pop up box I have a form with a few select fields and upon changing these slect fields a value in a span element should change. I have got this to work (actually with stackoverflow users help) but the solution doesn't work in IE8...suprise...suprise.

I make changes to the select field but the value does not change. I was wondering if anyone could give me any ideas why this might be the case by just having a look at the following JS code. Does the live function now work in IE8?!!

JS Code:

```
$('select.htt, select.hst').live('change', function() {
    var channels = parseInt($('#fancy_div select.hst').val(), 10) * parseInt($('#fancy_div select.htt').val(), 10);         
    $('#fancy_div span.yellow2').html(channels + 'Channels');
});
```

I have pasted the HTML here: http://www.copypastecode.com/13356/ - its a lot of HTML!

Thanks all for any help or guidance why this isn't working on IE. IE doesn't seem to register the changes of the select fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery live does work in IE8, but the [live handlers](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) don't support the change event.

> Possible event values: click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup
>
> Currently not supported: blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit

Comment: Ah I see - I did not know this. I guess click will have to do.

Answer (score 9):

`live` does not support the change event. From the [manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live):

> Possible event values: click,
>   dblclick, mousedown, mouseup,
>   mousemove, mouseover, mouseout,
>   keydown, keypress, keyup
>   Currently not supported:
>   blur, focus,
>   mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit

Answer (score -1):

Live also not support paste event Handler hence use bind