# Does jQuery Live work on Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just asked this question [an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624323/does-jqueries-live-work-in-ie8) but with regards to IE8 and I was told that the JQuery Live handlers does not support "change" so I switched over to "click", this solved my problem and now I find Safari does not work with click for some strange reason, anyone know why?

So I was thinking can I just have both?

```
$('select.htt, select.hst').live('click', function() {
    var channels = parseInt($('#fancy_div select.hst').val(), 10) * parseInt($('#fancy_div select.htt').val(), 10);         
    $('#fancy_div span.yellow2').html(channels + ' Channels');
});
```

And change(which works on safari)

```
$('select.htt, select.hst').live('change', function() {
    var channels = parseInt($('#fancy_div select.hst').val(), 10) * parseInt($('#fancy_div select.htt').val(), 10);         
    $('#fancy_div span.yellow2').html(channels + ' Channels');
});
```

Or is there something more elegant?

### EDIT

Maybe I can do a conditional. `if ($.browser.msie` But how would I do this with the above, the above is also in a `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: I haven't had any problems with "click" event bubbling in Safari.

Comment: "click" in the live handler? What safari version do you use and on what OS. Mine is on windows and its a version 4.

Comment: Safari  4 on Windows. Click events bubble just fine.  What have you done in attempts to debug the problem? Have you tried setting up your own version of what "live()" does in order to see whether the events are making to your container element(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select.htt, select.hst').live($.browser.msie?'click':'change', function() { ....
```

Comment: Thanks it a lot for this, helped me out no end. Good idea.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are running into a combination of issues here:

1. [The `change` event does not bubble in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265074/does-the-onchange-event-propagate), while the `click` event does
2. [The `click` event does not fire/buuble on `<select>`/`<option>` elements in Safari](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html), while the `change` event does

I'm not sure of the best way forward for your situation though.

Answer (score 1):

The change event shouldn't bubble in ANY browser.

I would just have your code re-bind the change handler whenever the menu is added to the DOM, or perhaps even add an onchange attribute to the select if it's generated by a server script.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the buglist (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677) adding following CSS to the element is a solution as well :

```
<style>
  element {
      cursor : pointer;
  }
</style>
```

Works on iphone4 with safari

[Reference](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677#comment:8)