# jQuery change event on <select> not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I've got a page with a variable number of `<select>` elements (which explains why I'm using event delegation here). When the user changes the selected option, I want to hide/show different content areas on the page. Here's the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').change(function(e) {
    var changed = $(e.target);

    if (changed.is('select[name="mySelectName"]')) {
      // Test the selected option and hide/show different content areas.
    }
  });
});
```

This works in Firefox and Safari, but in IE the change event doesn't fire. Anyone know why?

Comment: According to MSDN, the change event doesn't bubble in IE, so unless jQuery is doing some magic, event delegation won't work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `change` event does not bubble in IE (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85,loband).aspx) and [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html#t07)). You cannot use event delegation in tandem with it.

<strike>In fact, it is because of this IE bug that jQuery `live` had to officially exclude `change` from the [list of supported events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) (FYI the DOM spec states `change` [should bubble](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents))</strike>.<sup>[[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85,loband).aspx)]</sup>

With respect to your question, you can bind directly to each select:

```
$('#container select').change(/*...*/)
```

If you really want event delegation you *might* find some success trying what [this person did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625143/does-jquery-live-work-on-safari/1625670#1625670) and bind to `click` in IE only, which *does* bubble:

```
$('#container').bind($.browser.msie ? 'click' : 'change', function(event) {
    /* test event.type and event.target 
     * to capture only select control changes
     */
})
```

But this browser detection feels really wrong. I'd really try working with the former example (binding directly to the drop downs). Unless you have hundreds of `<select>` boxes, event delegation wouldn't buy you much here anyway.

---

<sub>[[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85,loband).aspx)] Note: jQuery >= 1.4 now simulates a bubbling `change` event in IE via [`live()`/`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).</sub>

Comment: This would be one of the cases you can't get away from browser testing since you can't really feature test. However, for a full solution, you'd have to also handle keyup for keyboard navigation

Comment: @Juan: some think feature detecting a bubbling event is possible. See http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/#comment-44332

Comment: That's cool, thanks. Overview of the link that is applicable here: The post is about detecting supported events. By checking for a 'change' event on a div, you'll know whether the change event bubbles, since a div doesn't have its own change event.

Answer (score 3):

Idea that might help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container select[name="mySelectName"]').change(function(e) {
    var s = $(e.target);
    if (s.val()=='1') //hide/show something;
  });
});
```

If you are using AJAX, try [live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#container select[name="mySelectName"]').live('change', function(e) {
        var s = $(e.target);
        if (s.val()=='1') //hide/show something;
      });
    });
```

Comment: `jQuery/live()` does not support the `change` event. See http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn

Comment: 1.4 supports change event for .live, but the event itself is still a mess in IE as far as I can tell.

Comment: .live() is deprecated now in 1.7.7.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly you will need to call blur() to have jQuery invoke change() on IE machines. Try something like:

```
$("select[name=mySelectName]").click(function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do the trick. The event still isn't fired, even when the <select> is blurred.

Comment: I don't think blur automatically fires change.  however, blur is propagated properly, so a solution might be a delegated blur event which fires the change event (you could even save the old value as data if you want to check if it's changed).  This is a hack.  Unfortunately the proper solution requires MS to fix old IE versions

Answer (score 3):

using jquery 1.4.4 (and i think 1.4.3) seems to be all good now.... the change event works consistently in my limited testing.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7. It works for selects which are on the page when it loads, but not for those dynamically added afterwards (I add a new row when you fill in the last existing row). The problem appears to be limited to IE 8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines to your page head, Sit back and relax! :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('select').bind('onChange',function(){$(this).blur()});});
```

Answer (score 1):

`onchange=doAction` will work in IE and Firefox, but its not supported in Chrome.

You need to use jQuery's `.change` event to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand why you need to double check the name of the select after receiving an event to it.

Do you by any chance have multiple  elements with the same id ?

Did you actually mean to say "#container select" instead of "#container" ?

Comment: No. I'm using event delegation because I don't want to attach the event to every single <select> on the page because there's the potential for dozens of them. By attaching it to the container, there's only a single attachment.

Comment: And there are other <select> elements on the page that I don't want this event to fire on.

Comment: You can add an ID to the select element itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply building upon the example set by "Crescent Flesh" for a cross-platform solution that will survive even if loading this SELECT inside #container via an AJAX call.

```
$('#container').bind($.browser.msie ? 'click' : 'change', function(event) {
  if ((event.type == 'click') || (event.type == 'change')) {
    if (event.target.toString().indexOf('Select') != -1) {
      var sWhich = $('#container SELECT').val();
      handleSelectionChange(sWhich);
    }
  }
});
```

Now you simply build the handleSelectionChange() function, renaming it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

IE requires change event to be placed inside document ready. This seems to bind the change event to the associated element. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

:D:D Wow, I was finding solution... Why think so complicated? 
Simply: 
`<select onchange="doAction">`

Comment: Besides the fact that the question is specifically about jQuery's "change" event, the asker is using event delegation.

Comment: Sorry, about little theme miss, but maybe it will help to someone who will be finding solution, none of this^ ideas doesn´t worked for me in IE 8 :(