# Changing input's value based on another input's value

Tags: javascript, forms

Let's say for example I have this code:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="">
<input class="uploadarea">
<span class="button">Browse</span>
```

Now I've setupped some css to change the default input file button's look, And now the question is, How do i change `.uploadarea`'s value depending on the value of `#file` when I select a file?

I currently have this code but I don't know what to do next.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
inputfile = x[0];
textbox = x[1];
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to use the filepath in the `input[type=file]` as the value of the input with a class `uploadarea`.

Comment: @user1099531 You can't get the path of a file with the file input element, just the filename.

Comment: Why are you using a class ? are there lots of these ?

Comment: ^nope, But some elements have the same styling as those ones.

Comment: Then to make this easier you really need to add an ID to the input you want to set the value of - cross browser support for getting elements based on class is not good ... unless you use something like jQuery ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `onchange` handler to handle the `change` event on the file event :

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="" onchange="something(this.value)">
<input id="somethinghere" class="uploadarea">
<span class="button">Browse</span>

function something(val) {
    document.getElementById('somethinghere').value = val;
}
```

You need to add the `id` attribute for this to work

Comment: Should I put this in the head or before `</body>`?

Comment: you can put the script in the <head> as its triggered - ie not relying on the DOM being ready

Comment: Weird. The value is `undefined`.

Comment: When I selected a file, the value of `somethinghere` is now `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple **jQuery** code:

```
$('#file').change(function(){
    $('.uploadarea').val(this.value);
});
```

pure **Javascript**:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="foo()" />
<input class="uploadarea" id="other" />

function foo(){
    document.getElementById('other').value = this.value
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not include jQuery.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not fully supported on <= IE8 -> http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `onchange`.
And by the way read [alternate to onchange event in <input type='file' />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133807/alternate-to-onchange-event-in-input-type-file). There are some problems with JS manipulation after file select.