# input type="file" onchange event, cross browser solution

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

Im using a jquery ajax file upload: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

```
<input type="file" id="foo" name="foo" />
```

My problem is that the jquery change event does not fire:

```
$('#foo').change(function(){
    console.log('change');
});
```

Ive tried using the `on('change', function(){  })` method as well, without success.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does not fire in which browsers?  Did you look at [2133807](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133807/alternate-to-onchange-event-in-input-type-file)?

Comment: I did the test in firefox. @Ktash I suppose it has something to do with the plugin

Comment: What is it you are accomplishing with this plugin? A lot of the features it adds (like `serialize`) are standard in the latest jQuery. Also, since I deleted my comment, the [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/NnMKg/) again.

Comment: Check again and check out this fiddle and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/A8XP3/

Comment: @mcometa your fiddle doesn't use the file upload plugin, I think that is causing the problem. Change event is triggered normally without it.

Comment: @Johan could you provide a jsfiddle example of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might that your problem is in the order of the bindings.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ttamminen/NdVyJ/) is a jsFiddle that I used for testing. I have linked the plugin to this solution and it seems that the change event is triggered only if binding is done before `.ajaxForm`.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Actually [it works either way](http://jsfiddle.net/NdVyJ/4/) for me (tested in Chrome and FF 9), but I had to fix the forms url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Dont know if its bad to use .live, but works for me, when the normal way dosnt

```
$('#foo').live('change',function(){
    alert('change');
});
```