# Fire javascript event onchange event of <input type="file"/>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, blueimp

I have this code

```
<input id="fileupload" 
       type="file" name="files[]" 
       class="inputFile clickable" 
       onchange="uploadFile(this.value)"/>
```

This works fine on second time using it, i.e. first time I select the file the onchange event does not fire, but selecting file for the second time works fine.

Is there any thing which I can change here?

I have tried:

- `onlclick` (doesn't work, fires before selecting file)
- `onblur` (doesn't work, doesn't fire at all, plus even if does, its just stupid to click somewhere else on page to fire the operation)
- `onselect` (doesn't work)

Additional info:
If I use `onchange=alert(this.value)` it works fine

this is my javascript code

```
function uploadFile(value) {
     alert(value); //works fine
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'fileUpload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
//        done: function (e, data) {
//            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
//                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
//            });
//        },
        success: function() {
            showMultipleDataDiv(value); //but I don't get value here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: similar thread ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133807/alternate-to-onchange-event-in-input-type-file

Comment: yeah, but that does not change the situation, I create a new input and it still fires on second time and not first.

Comment: Can you post your Javascript code? Maybe there are some errors in there?

Comment: Can you please try using jquery live method like $('#fileupload').live('change', function(){ uploadFile(); }); or like $("#fileupload").change(function() { 
  alert('I clicked');
});

Comment: If you have access to error logs look at them and else try using the Chrome Network console (right-click page -> Inspect Element -> Network tab) and then submitting the upload form. I think there is something wrong with your fileUpload.php.

Comment: I doubt, cause when I see the get request for showmultipledatadiv it is empty, plus I didn't write fileupload.php this is from blueimp plugin

Answer (score 1):

The code `$('#fileupload').fileupload` will trigger a file upload as soon as the user selects a file. You need to run this code before the user selects a file, because it adds an event listener to the input tag. Since you only run this code after the user selects a file, then it will only work on the second time.

This is the change you need to do to make it work

```
$(function () {
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'fileUpload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
    //        done: function (e, data) {
    //            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
    //                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
    //            });
    //        },
    success: function () {
      showMultipleDataDiv(value); //but I don't get value here
    }
  });
});
```

Notice there is no need to add code in the change event. The plugin is going to do that for you.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin