# How do I force a blur event to occur in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I want to do.  I want to trigger an event every time a select element changes.  I have a multiline select and when I make changes (click on elements), it does not change until the select box loses focus.  So I'm trying to force a blur every time the select box is clicked.  That way if it changes, it will trigger the changed event.  If it doesn't change, nothing will happen.

How do I do this?  Am I even approaching this the right way? Jquery answers are okay as well.

Comment: If you do this you are going to piss off those of use who use the keyboard to navigate through the select list options.

Comment: @Roatin, that depends. If he's changing a label class, no biggy, if he's tossing an alert... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,  Here's what was going on.  I was including the -vsdoc version of JQuery instead of the actual JQuery library.  This also fixes some issues I was having with some plugins such as blockUI.

Comment: To clarify, you do NOT want to include the -vsdoc.  This should be used for intellisense only.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Ender the full code could be something like this.

```
$('#mySelectBox').change(function() {
    $('#thingToBlur').blur();
})
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 6):

This will find the element with the focus and trigger the blur event.

```
function blur(){
    document.querySelectorAll('input,textarea').forEach(function(element){
        if(element === document.activeElement) {
            return element.blur();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery do:

```
$('#mySelectBox').change(function() {
   //do things here
});
```

According to the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/change/, the event is triggered immediately when the user makes a selection.

Check out this demo to verify that this works: http://jsfiddle.net/AHM8j/

Comment: Yes. This is the event the OP should be listening for.

Comment: This might not happen in IE. IE is notoriously bad with the `change` event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie

Comment: That demo I provided seems to me to be working in IEs 6-8.  Additionally, from the documentation provided: "As of jQuery 1.4 the change event now bubbles, and works identically to all other browsers, in Internet Explorer."

Comment: That's what I thought.  What's super frustrating is that when I copy and paste my code into that demo site, it works as expected.  But when I run it within my application, it doesn't.  Maybe it has something to do with Microsoft's AJAX libraries.  I more/less inherited this code and so there's a number of extra unused javascript libraries being referenced.

Comment: Try using jQuery.noConflict() and then (for the sake of convenience) wrap your jQuery in this: (function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
})(jQuery);  I can't guarantee that will fix your problem, but it can't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You could attach an onclick handler to the select and the individual options. basically `onclick="this.blur();"`. I've always found that click events on `<select>` elements to be a pain, as nothing happens at the point you expect it to.