# jQuery + Ruby on Rails Repeating Code

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery method:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select[name='publication_type[category]'] ").change(function (){
          alert("It works");

       });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

It operates on the following ruby code:

```
select("publication_type", "category", @filters.selections.collect(&:name), :id =>"publication_type" )
```

Each time I choose a different option from the drop down box, the alert method fires twice. The intention is that it should only fire once. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the double alert, but don't use the "change" event. IE does not fire the change event on a select element until it loses focus, not when the value changes.

edit: same goes for radio buttons and checkboxes.

Comment: So what method would you use instead?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem...I had added the javascript file in two places...one in the layout template and another in the view that was being rendered.