# Using $(this) in combination with live/delegate in IE6-7?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I cannot seem to get the value from a select option that has been dynamically created when viewing in IE6/IE7. IE always returns undefined as the value.

I have a set up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2wkd/1/), and below is the complete source of an example (in case you attempt to use fiddle in IE6/7 ...heh):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var json = "blah blah blah";

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myForm').html('<select id="sg-1" class="setgroup" name="sg-1"><option value="s-1">Something</option><option value="s-2">Another</option><option value="s-3">Third</option><option value="s-4">Fourth</option></select>');

    $('.setgroup').live('change',function(){
        updateSelected($(this + ':selected').val(), json);
    });

});

function updateSelected(value, json){
    //do some stuff with the json in my app
    $('#selected').html(value + ' was selected');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
</form>
<p id="selected" style="font-size:20px; color:#f00;"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The examples use live(), however I have also tried a variation using .delegate(). Both methods work in all browsers except IE6/7. I have tried using click as the event as well. Any ideas?

I also tried the solution(s) provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie). The problem seems to be in $(this) not being interpreted correctly, as if I place an alert inside of the live/change/delegate it will fire properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this + ':selected')` will not work. It will try to concatenate the string representation of a DOM element, which will probably be `[object HTMLSelectElement]`,  with `:selected`, resulting in the "selector"  `$('[object HTMLSelectElement]:selected')`.

I think you just want `$(this)`. A `select` cannot be `selected` anyway.

In general, if you already have a set of selected elements, you can filter for certain elements with [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). If you want to find specific descendants, then use [`.find()`  *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

---

However, you can also attach the event handler after you inserted the element:

```
// or $('#sg-1').change(...
$('.setgroup').change(function(){
    updateSelected($(this).val(), json);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2wkd/6/)

Comment: My original respone was in err -- $(this) does in fact work with `live` in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: The problem was apparently the string concatenation: `$(this + ':selected')` -- IE freaks, apparently other browsers drop the concatenation and just attempt $(this), which works.

Comment: @hztetra: It should not work in any browser, but you are right, it works in Chrome. Strange.... I hope you know now that least that it is wrong to concatenate `this` with a string. It does not matter that it works in other browsers, it is not correct.

Comment: @hztetra: No, it does not ignore the concatenation. You can try `alert($(this + ':selected').selector)` to see the result selector. I don't know why it works.

Comment: I sure do, and am in the process of seeing if I attempted that any where else :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.setgroup').live('change',function(){
    updateSelected($(this).val(), json);
});
```

Comment: It does in fact work -- it was an err on my part (saving one file and looking at another ;) ). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.setgroup').live('change',function(){
    updateSelected($(this).val(), json);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your selector.  You are trying to concatenate an element reference with a string.  This will not give you a valid selector.  To correct it you want either:

```
$(":selected", this)
```

or:

```
$(this).find(":selected")
```

But, better than either of these options would be to just use `.val()` on the select directly:

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$('.setgroup').live('change',function(){

        updateSelected($(this).find(':selected').val(), json);

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q2wkd/3/

Answer (score 1):

> For future visitors :

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated now. For cross-browser support, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) when you are using jQuery 1.7+ or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in lower versions.

.on() example :

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.setgroup', function(){
      updateSelected($(this).val(), json); // your javascript code goes here
});
```

.delegate() example :

```
$(document).delegate('.setgroup', 'change', function() {
    updateSelected($(this).val(), json); // your javascript code goes here
});
```