# jQuery .change() event not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a dialog that performs a calculation that is dependant on three input fields.  When any of them are changed it checks whether they are all filled and if they are it processes and gives its response.

It works absolutely fine in FF, Chrome, Opera etc, but in any version of IE it just stops working.  The rest of my jQuery works fine, but I can't work out exactly where the problem is here.  I think it might be to do with the .change() event or the multiple event binding but I really don't know.

Here's the offending code:

```
var loan = $("#ltv-loan-amount");
var mortgage = $("#ltv-mortgage");
var property = $("#ltv-property");

$("#ltv-dialog input").change( function() {
    if(loan.val() && mortgage.val() && property.val())
    {
        var ltv = parseInt( ( ( parseInt(loan.val()) + parseInt(mortgage.val()) ) / parseInt(property.val()) )* 1000 );
        ltv /= 10;
        if(ltv > 0 && ltv < 85)
        {
            $("#ltv-result").html("<span id=\"ltv-form-result\">" + ltv + "%</span></p><p><a id=\"ltv-link\" href=\"#sidebar-head\">Congratulations, your LTV has passed. Please now proceed with your application opposite.</a>");
            $("#amount").val(loan.val());
            $("#mortgage_balance").val(mortgage.val());
            $("#prop_value").val(property.val());
            $("#ltv-link").click(function() {
                $( "#ltv-dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
            });
        }
        else if (ltv > 84)
        {
            $("#ltv-result").html("<span id=\"ltv-form-result\">" + ltv + "%</span></p><p>Unfortunately your LTV is greater than 85%. You may still qualify for a loan if you reduce the loan amount.");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#ltv-result").html("</p><p>Please check your input above as you currently have a negative ltv.");
        }
    }
});
```

and the HTML in question:

```
<div id="ltv-dialog" title="Do You Qualify for a Loan?">
    <p>Please enter the fields below and your LTV will be calculated automatically.</p>
    <div id="ltv-form">
        <div class="ltv-row">
            <label for="ltv-loan-amount">Loan Amount:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ltv-loan-amount" id="ltv-loan-amount" class="p000" />
        </div>
        <div class="ltv-row">
            <label for="ltv-mortgage">Mortgage Value:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ltv-mortgage" id="ltv-mortgage" class="p000" />
        </div>
        <div class="ltv-row">
            <label for="ltv-property">Estimated Property Value:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ltv-property" id="ltv-property" class="p000" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ltv-row">
        <p>Loan to Value % (LTV): <span id="ltv-result"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**An Update**

The change event appears to be firing, but only when the text box changes from a value to null.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I think the following post will help you out:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML.  If you're using radio buttons or checkboxes, then you probably want to listen for `.click()` instead of `.change()`.

Comment: Where do you declare the variables `loan`, `mortgage` and `property`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - the console is clean.

Comment: @guffa - the variables are posted just above (have edited to indicate)

Comment: It is a bug with IE, see this previous thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie

Comment: @jfriend00 - have edited to include relevant HTML

Comment: I've tried the code using jsfiddle (in IE9) using dev tools + quirksmode, ie7, ie8 and ie9. It works in all for me.

Comment: When I try it, it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/EEe4w/ I see a logical error in the code, though. If the LTV is exactly 85%, you get the message that it's greater than 85%, as you use `< 85` in the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you are targeting text input elements, have you tried using a different event? So instead of `change` use, for example, `keyup`? `$("#ltv-dialog input").keyup( function() {`. This will fire after every keypress.

Comment: This worked perfectly - even improved on what I was trying to acheive.

Comment: This is a workaround but not exactly a solution. Change and Keyup are just different events.

Comment: @Max The `Change` event waits for you to finish interacting with and leaving the input field, e.g. when you have finished typing and leave the input. `keyup` will trigger every time you press a key on the keyboard, i.e. as you type.

Comment: @Richar I am aware. That's why I don't see a solution in the answer. If the user wanted the event to fire every time a button was pressed the question should be different. Nonetheless your answer seemed to have satisfied the user who asked - so we can all be happy. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery `.on()` also might solve your problem. Use it like this :

```
jQuery("#ltv-dialog").on("change", "input", function(){
     alert("It works !");
     //your javascript/jQuery goes here
   }
);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8FaU/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: Below fix worked for me:

Instead of: `$("#ltv-dialog input").change( function() {`

I used: `$('#ltv-dialog').on('input', function() {`

Answer (score -1):

Please try with using **each** instead of **change** / **click** , which is working fine even first time in IE as well as other browsers

Not Working a first time

```
$("#checkboxid").change(function () {

});
```

**Working fine even first time**

```
$("#checkboxid").each(function () {

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the live function, it usually makes it work ...

```
$("#YOURTHING").live("change", function(){

// CODE HERE

});
```

Comment: .live (and .delegate) are deprecated since jQuery 1.7. We should use .bind or .on to attach an event to a selector. 

.bind will not attach the event to elements that are being appended dynamically to the DOM where .on will attach the events even if the elements are being appended dynamically to the DOM.

Comment: .live doesn't work on IE browsers