# jQuery alert not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have the following script that is not working in IE 8, it works in other browsers fine but in IE 8... all the user gets, even with the checkbox input selected is alert. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
    $("form#insider-account").bind("keypress", function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
    });

   var isChecked = false;

   $("form#insider-account").change(function() {
      if ($("input#insideraccount_verified").is(":checked")) {
         isChecked = true; 
      } else {
         isChecked = false;   
      }
   });

   $("form#insider-account").submit(function(e) {
      if (!isChecked) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("You must agree that the information you provided is correct.");
      }
      else {

      }
   });
});
```

Comment: alert() is not jQuery.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jquery 2.0 is not supporting IE 8

Comment: Is the change function being called? Use the console to find out.

Comment: Is `$("form#insider-account").submit(function(e) { alert('Hi')});` works?

Comment: make sure you have enabled script in InternetOption?

Comment: Yes @MarcellFülöp alert is not jQuery, maybe I should have worded my post jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you set isChecked in a separate event from the submit-event. I think your problem is that in IE8, this:

```
 $("form#insider-account").change(...
```

Isn't triggered when a control inside the form is changed. Why not attach the change event to the control itself:

```
$("input#insideraccount_verified").change(...
```

Or, better, just check that the checkbox is checked in the submit event instead of using a variable that you set in some other event:

```
$("form#insider-account").submit(function (e) {
            if (!$("input#insideraccount_verified").is(":checked")) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("You must agree that the information you provided is correct.");
            }
            else {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried the example provided but not preventing the form from submitting if the checkbox isn't checked.

Comment: Do you get the alert though? You may have to add a "return false" after the alert for IE.

Comment: No I do not get the alert, the form just submits.

Comment: I stand correct, after noticing your example was missing a { everything is working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for change on elements inside the form instead of the form iteself, after searching google for "form change ie jquery" there were a number of results stating that this was an issue including [jQuery .change() event not firing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921498/jquery-change-event-not-firing-in-ie)

It's suggested there to use the on event instead, which will listen to the change event for input elements inside your form, like so:

```
$("form#insider-account input").on('change', function() {
    isChecked = $("input#insideraccount_verified").is(":checked");
});
```

Comment: Your code seems to do the same thing mine did, works in Chrome, but doesn't work in IE 8.

Comment: If it doesn't bubble the way he's currently doing it, it won't work this way either as it depends on that same bubbling. In a sense it's identical to what's in the OP. the edit is better.

Comment: @KevinB true.. i was going off the suggestions in that thread. Edited to be directly listening to the input changes.