# Jquery not supported in IE6 and IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using the plugin **jquery-1.4.1.js** and **jquery-1.4.1.min.js** .

I have a function like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#DropDownList1').change(function () {
                alert('changed');
            });
        });
```

This works fine in firefox and chrome.But not working in IE6 IE7. But one thing i know IE supports Activexobjects. Is there any way to convert jquery objects to Activexobjects. please help.

Comment: 1.4.1 definitely supports IE6+. The problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie

Comment: Are you really including both the non-minified *and* the minified version of jQuery? Don't do that. Also, why use an ancient version? The latest is 1.9.1.

Comment: use jquery latest version and then try.

Comment: IE6, is he still alive? :)

Comment: Have you checked DropDownList1 is unique?

Comment: @james ya it is unique

Comment: @juhana does IE6 and IE7 supports latest version of jquery. I don't think so

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj: yes they support. what made you think they don't support?

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj 1.9.x supports IE 6+. 2.0 supports IE 9+. http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @defau1t It is not supporting the older version how can it support new version.

Comment: Check out my answer. It is supporting older as well as newer versions. Something else wrong in your code.

Comment: don't support ie6! http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @pete some clients are still using ie6!

Comment: hahaha punish them for not upgrading!

Comment: @pete they are still using basic microsoft's xp os :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are including the jQuery twice. jquery-1.4.1.js and jquery-1.4.1.min.js  should essentially be the same with jquery-1.4.1.min.js  being the compressed version of code. Try getting rid of one version and you should be home.