# $('body').on('click','.class_name', function(){}); not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a block clickable by a class named atnd_modal and opening a modal popup on click

I am doing this-

```
$('body').on('click','.atnd_modal', function(){
//modal opening code here 

});
```

Its working fine in chrome and other browser but its not working in IE.
I also tried window instead of body but its not working.

and its working when i am trying with IE in useragent.

How can i make this working in IE ?

Comment: don't see any problem in this code. Is something else is failing? do you see any error in IE's developer console?

Comment: show your modal opening code

Comment: I think code is fine, no problem with the code. can you show your modal open code.

Comment: firstly i added a div with id="myModal_attend"  and then appending inner html by  ----  $('#myModal_attend').html(modal_html); where  modal_html='<h3 style="font-size:30px;" class="pd_btm_modal">Thanks for '+res1+'ing '+name+'</h3></br><h3 style="text-align:center;color:white";>You will get update </>';    and at last   $('#myModal_attend').modal('toggle');

Comment: check if javascript is enabled in IE..

Comment: What is the version of jQuery and IE you are using?

Comment: jquery--- jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js and IE 9

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625143/does-jquery-live-work-on-safari/1625670#1625670

Comment: Thanks everyone for help . Now i got the issue. the issue was cookie was  not working in case of IE. and i was usiing this cookie inside click function.

Answer (score 0):

jquery `on` requires jquery version `1.7` or later ..try `delegate` if your version is below

```
$('body').delegate('.atnd_modal','click', function(){
//modal opening code here 

});
```

And most importantly make sure to check jquery is included

Comment: Sunil's code is working fine on other browsers. So no issue with JQuery version.

Comment: coolguy is delegate for IE only or for all browser bcoz its not working in other.

Comment: @vijayP if the version is jquery2.0 than it wont work in ie8

Comment: @coolguy then how you suggested to use `delegate`. You really don't know the context...:)